# ARM : Get network Interface Private IP and Default Gateway

Tags: azure, automation, azure-resource-manager

im deploying an ARM template for a virtual machine with network interfaces

i have a .sh script that needs parameters to be passed to it

**parameters :**

> NIC private ip

> NIC default Gateway

**nic template :**

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('nic2name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "ipConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "ipconfig1",
        "properties": {
          "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
          "subnet": {
            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
          },
          "primary": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "primary": false
  }
}
```

im sitting variables to get this parameters but idk how to get them

```
"smnet_dev": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('nic2name')).ipConfigurations]",
"smnet_dflt_gw": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('nic2name')).<default gateway>]"
```

i hope someone can guide me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***AFAIK, We can not give it directly instead of that we can use PowerShell script or [**`bicep`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource) which will retrieve the value of nic and put it in variable.***

*In ARM while we are creating resources (e.g virtual machine with nic) we can add the variable as following and then we can deploy the NIC with gateways.*

*Things we have tried to create a virtual Machine with nic and provide the variable as shown below it got succeed .*

*You can use the below template by passing your required name in parameter file for the Automation.*

`Template.json`:-

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"location": {
"type": "string"
},
"networkInterfaceName": {
"type": "string"
},
"enableAcceleratedNetworking": {
"type": "bool"
},
"networkSecurityGroupName": {
"type": "string"
},
"networkSecurityGroupRules": {
"type": "array"
},
"subnetName": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualNetworkName": {
"type": "string"
},
"addressPrefixes": {
"type": "array"
},
"subnets": {
"type": "array"
},
"publicIpAddressName": {
"type": "string"
},
"publicIpAddressType": {
"type": "string"
},
"publicIpAddressSku": {
"type": "string"
},
"pipDeleteOption": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineName": {
"type": "string"
},

"virtualMachineComputerName": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineRG": {
"type": "string"
},
"osDiskType": {
"type": "string"
},
"osDiskDeleteOption": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineSize": {
"type": "string"
},
"nicDeleteOption": {
"type": "string"
},
"adminUsername": {
"type": "string"
},
"adminPassword": {
"type": "secureString"
},
"patchMode": {
"type": "string"
},
"enableHotpatching": {
"type": "bool"
},
"tags": {
 "type": "object"
 }
 },
"variables": {
                              "nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
                              "vnetName": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
                              "vnetId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name,'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
                              "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
                      
},
                              "resources": [
                                  {
                                      "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
                                      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
                                      "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                                      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                      "dependsOn": [
                                          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
                                          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
                                          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                                      ],
                                      "properties": {
                                          "ipConfigurations": [
                                              {
                                                  "name": "ipconfig1",
                                                  "properties": {
                                                      "subnet": {
                                                          "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                                                      },
                                                      "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                                                      "publicIpAddress": {
                                                          "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]",
                                                          "properties": {
                                                              "deleteOption": "[parameters('pipDeleteOption')]"
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          ],
                                          "enableAcceleratedNetworking": "[parameters('enableAcceleratedNetworking')]",
                                          "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                              "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
                                          }
                                      },
                                      "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
                                      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
                                      "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
                                      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                      "properties": {
                                          "securityRules": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupRules')]"
                                      },
                                      "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
                                      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                                      "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
                                      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                      "properties": {
                                          "addressSpace": {
                                              "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
                                          },
                                          "subnets": "[parameters('subnets')]"
                                      },
                                      "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
                                      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
                                      "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
                                      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                      "properties": {
                                          "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]"
                                      },
                                      "sku": {
                                          "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressSku')]"
                                      },
                                      "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                                      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                                      "apiVersion": "2021-07-01",
                                      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                      "dependsOn": [
                                          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                                      ],
                                      "properties": {
                                          "hardwareProfile": {
                                              "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                                          },
                                          "storageProfile": {
                                              "osDisk": {
                                                  "createOption": "fromImage",
                                                  "managedDisk": {
                                                      "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                                                  },
                                                  "deleteOption": "[parameters('osDiskDeleteOption')]"
                                              },
                                              "imageReference": {
                                                  "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                                                  "offer": "WindowsServer",
                                                  "sku": "2019-datacenter-gensecond",
                                                  "version": "latest"
                                              }
                                          },
                                          "networkProfile": {
                                              "networkInterfaces": [
                                                  {
                                                      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]",
                                                      "properties": {
                                                          "deleteOption": "[parameters('nicDeleteOption')]"
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              ]
                                          },
                                          "osProfile": {
                                              "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineComputerName')]",
                                              "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                                              "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                                              "windowsConfiguration": {
                                                  "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                                                  "provisionVmAgent": true,
                                                  "patchSettings": {
                                                      "enableHotpatching": "[parameters('enableHotpatching')]",
                                                      "patchMode": "[parameters('patchMode')]"
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          },
                                          "licenseType": "Windows_Server"
                                      },
                                      "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
                                  }
                              ],
                              "outputs": {
                                  "adminUsername": {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
                                  }
                              }
                          }
```

***From this aforementioned script here is our NIC template*** ;

```
"resources": [
                                  {
                                      "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
                                      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
                                      "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                                      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                      "dependsOn": [
                                          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
                                          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
                                          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                                      ],
                                      "properties": {
                                          "ipConfigurations": [
                                              {
                                                  "name": "ipconfig1",
                                                  "properties": {
                                                      "subnet": {
                                                          "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                                                      },
                                                      "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                                                      "publicIpAddress": {
                                                          "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]",
                                                          "properties": {
                                                              "deleteOption": "[parameters('pipDeleteOption')]"
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          ],
```

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **SIMILAR SO THREAD**|[***ARM Template - Get a private ip address from a network interface id***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71411102/arm-template-get-a-private-ip-address-from-a-network-interface-id) & [***Cannot find VirtualNetwork with name' creating a 'Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments' resource***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517801/azure-arm-template-cannot-find-virtualnetwork-with-name-creating-a-microsof?rq=1) .